# `systemd` messages after starting login

Tags: login, systemd

After boot-up process `systemd` starts `agetty`, but after 1--2 seconds additional messages are appeared:

[image: Photo]

How to avoid this?

I use Arch Linux, systemd 194.

```
$ grep '^[^#]' /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
[Unit]
Description=Getty on %I
Documentation=man:agetty(8)
After=systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service
After=rc-local.service
Before=getty.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes
ConditionPathExists=/dev/tty0

[Service]
Environment=TERM=linux
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I 38400
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
Environment=LANG= LANGUAGE= LC_CTYPE= LC_NUMERIC= LC_TIME= LC_COLLATE= LC_MONETARY= LC_MESSAGES= LC_PAPER= LC_NAME= LC_ADDRESS= LC_TELEPHONE= LC_MEASUREMENT= LC_IDENTIFICATION=
KillSignal=SIGHUP

[Install]
Alias=getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54247

The only workaround, for the time being, is to use the `quiet` parameter in your kernel line.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The problem is that netcfg takes ages (at least in my case), and that getty does not wait for netcfg (or more generally, network.target) to finish.  Hence, the solution is to make getty wait.

For this, the easiest approach is to make additional configurations to the getty@.service unit file.  Fortunately systemd allows us to do this without directly overwriting any files. Just create the folder `/etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/` and add the file `custom.conf` inside it (actually, any filename will do, as long as it ends in .conf).

Within custom.conf you have to write:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target
```

And that should do the trick